# Python, JSON. How can I get a value from keys with the same name?

Tags: python, json

I need to grab "sid" value from my JSON

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "customName": "name-1",
            "sid": "1247azc08belr2q4"
            },
        {
            "customName": "name-2",
            "sid": "zz63p2xxeh32b661"
            },
        {
            "customName": "name-3",
            "sid": "aa88p2xfeh32e661"
            }
    ]
}
```

I tried to do

```
customName_1 = 'name-1'
customName_2 = 'name-2'
customName_3 = 'name-3'
for name in My_JSON['response']:
        if name['customName'] == customName_3:
            print(name['sid'])
        else:
            print('Cant get sid')
```

But it's not work because i grab "sid" from the first "customName" (name-1). Help me please with this.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work - where do you define `My_JSON`? Try printing it just before the for-loop

Comment: Your code works fine for me, gives the `sid` from `name-3`

Comment: Do you need to return all three sid values, without passing customName explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this snippet to return all 3 `sid` values....

```
MY_JSON = {
        "response": [
            {
                "customName": "name-1",
                "sid": "1247azc08belr2q4"
                },
            {
                "customName": "name-2",
                "sid": "zz63p2xxeh32b661"
                },
            {
                "customName": "name-3",
                "sid": "aa88p2xfeh32e661"
                }
        ]
    }

names = ["name-1", "name-2", "name-3"];

for name in MY_JSON['response']:
    if name['customName'] in names:
        print(name['sid'])
    else:
        print('Cant get sid')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will store all the relevant 'sid'-values in the list `sids`. You could do this easily with `json` library as shown below. 
Also, I used list comprehension to make your code more concise.

```py
import json

d = json.loads(s)
sids = [customer['sid'] for customer in d['response'] if (customer['customName']=='name-3')]
print(sids)
```

**Output**:

```
['aa88p2xfeh32e661']
```

> If you want `sid` values from all the customers, you could use the following piece of code.

```py
sids = [customer['sid'] for customer in d['response']]
```

#### Dummy Data

```
s = """
{
    "response": [
        {
            "customName": "name-1",
            "sid": "1247azc08belr2q4"
            },
        {
            "customName": "name-2",
            "sid": "zz63p2xxeh32b661"
            },
        {
            "customName": "name-3",
            "sid": "aa88p2xfeh32e661"
            }
    ]
}
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

I sketched simple solution that might do what need.

```py
def grab_item_by_attr(lst, attr_name, attr_value):
  result = None

  for item in lst:
    if item[attr_name] == attr_value:
      result = item

  return result
```

When you call it, the result would be item you need:

```
>>> item = grab_item_by_attr(data['response'], 'customName', 'name-3')
>>> item
{'customName': 'name-3', 'sid': 'aa88p2xfeh32e661'}
>>> item['sid']
'aa88p2xfeh32e661'
```

I hope it helps!